Why does the BitKepp (BitGet) wallet display isMetaMask:true in its properties?

I tried it in different browsers with and without MetaMask installed.

I need this to accurately determine the wallet.

Browsers and websites have been doing something similar for decades with userAgent "Mozilla AppleWebKit like Gecko Chrome". Probably it will never stop.

Understood thanks
